# Avoid nesting when decorator has many parameters

Tags: python, python-3.x, optimization, nested, decorator

I am creating a kind of HTTP framework in Python.
I decided to create an @http decorator and define methods, arguments, etc. as decorator arguments.

It was good at first, but halfway through, I created a doc argument to automatically generate the documentation.
Here is my code.

```py
@http("GET", args=(
    Argument("text", "string", maximum=32,
                   doc=Document(title="Input text.")),
    Argument("count", "integer", minimum=1, maximum=100,
                   doc=Document(title="Multiple count."))),
            require_auth=False,
            doc=Document("Repeats the string specified with text.",
                                types="application/json",
                                responses=[
                                    Response(200, "Successful response.", {
                                        "success": True,
                                        "result": "Hello, world!"
                                    })
                                ]))
def get(request): pass
```

The problem I'm having is that the @http nesting is too deep.
Does anyone have any ideas on how to avoid this nesting?

My idea is to add more decorators, such as @docs, but I don't want to use this change because it would significantly change the internal behavior.

I am using a translator, so if you have any questions, please comment and I will do my best to answer them. If you have any questions or comments, please comment to me.

Thank you.

Comment: Yeah that really doesn't look desirable. You could either use one of the docs frameworks already available (like swagger) or, if you really want to make the docs generator yourself, think of using the `Document` class in a way that you can inherit from it and create documentation classes with the information stored in the attributes.

Comment: Thank you for your comment.
The one I am creating was originally created to make it easier to create an HTTP API.
I've already created one that converts Python code to Swagger, and previously used it by overriding methods like get_doc().
I hadn't thought of a way to inherit from the Document class. Thanks for the great suggestion.